# spring, get json keys in the controller function

Tags: json, spring, post, controller, spring-data

i am sending a JSON object to my controller using POST method inside the request body (using post man).

i want to receive the JSON parameters as variables of my controller function

for ample when i send this

```
{"A":"some a value", "B":"Some b value"}
```

i want to get them like this in my controller

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/api/some-update-url"    , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    Boolean updateSomeData(@RequestParam String A, @RequestParam String B) {
        ..... 
    }
}
```

but this is the result of my postman

```
{
    "timestamp": 1490896822946,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
    "message": "Required Gender parameter 'gender' is not present",
    "path": "/api/some-update-url"
}
```

can you help me please

thank you !!

Comment: In your question you say you send "POST" request but in code the request mapping is "PUT" - these are totally different methods - so I don't see how it can work, if its mistake in a question - please refine it.

Answer (score 1):

@RequestParam annotated parameters get linked to specific Servlet request parameters. Parameter values are converted to the declared method argument type. This annotation indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter.

If I were to pass email in as a request parameter, for example, I would annotate the method in my controller as such:

```
@RequestParam(value = "email", required = true) String email
```

Calling such method would be done like:

```
http://some.service.url/verification?email=someone@somewhere.com
```

Comment: thank you, will it work with post, when sending parameters in the body  ?

Comment: It will work with POST as well. If you want to send stuff in the body, you need to use the @RequestBody annotation instead. Also note that body is a JSON object so you will pass a POJO not just a String.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestParam is used to map POST/GET request parameters. What you are doing is sending JSON as the body of the request. In that case you need to use @RequestBody parameter on one of your Controller's method parameters.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/some-update-url", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
Boolean updateSomeData(@RequestBody MyClass myClass) {
   ..... 
}
```

You can further read about @RequestBody here:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody-demystified.html

Comment: hey thank you, i know that, but i prefer not to create a class for each request, is it possible just writing the variable in the controller ?